# PHP after a click on <a href> content in text file is deleted

Tags: php, file

I have a problem : I want to store variable in every pages of my project, but each time I click on a link in my page, the folder is cleaning. 
I also try with session variable but it's the same.

My code first page:

```
<?php

echo '
     <form action"test.php" method="post">
         clé ak : <input type="text" name="ak" /><br><br>
         clé as : <input type="text" name ="as" />
         <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
      <a href="get-key3.php" target="_blank">take token</a>';
?>
```

And the page test.php :

```
<?php

file_put_contents("cles.txt",$_POST["ak"]."\n".$_POST["as"]);

require_once('OvhApi.php');
$action=@$_GET["action"];
$ovh = new OvhApi();
$resp = array();

echo '<a href="test.php?action=1">info</a><br>
      <a href="test.php?action=2">domain</a><br>';
switch($action)
{
      case 1:
              $resp = $ovh->get('/me');
              var_dump($resp);
              break;
      case 2:
             $resp = $ovh->get('/domain');
             var_dump($resp);
             break;
}
?>
```

Thank's for your help.

Comment: If you have method post on your form then how are you trying to get GET variable?

Comment: In order to pass variable in session, you need session_start() on each page.

Comment: It's not your main problem but please take out the bad and unneeded `fclose("cles.txt");`.

Comment: When I have tried with session I had add session_start() on every pages, and I want to get variable because I want to put it in my class page.

Comment: I have never met such expression @_GET["action"]; (I mean get with @ sign instead of dollar sign). Is that for skipping errors instead of checking with Isset() ?

Comment: Thank's Julie Pelletier if there is some mistakes in my code ! :D

Comment: Please `var_export()` the return value of `file_put_contents`.

Comment: It return 49 after form, and 1 after click.

Comment: If just forgot "$" between "@" and "_GET['action']" sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a beginner I'm not sure if this will be usefull to you, but I have been playing with text-files as well.

```
$myfile = fopen("cles.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$ak = $_POST['ak']."\r\n";
fwrite($myfile, $ak);
$as = $_POST['as']."\r\n";
fwrite($myfile, $as);
fclose($myfile);
```

"a+" here stands for: Open for reading and writing; If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. Writes are always appended.
There are other options with fopen(); function.

The source I used was:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a very simple manner. First we will create the link.

```
<a href="test.php?clear=yes">Clear file content</a>
```

Note that I have passed a `clear=yes` parameter to `test.php`. We will now use this to make sure the link has been clicked.

```
if (issset($_GET['clear']) && $_GET['clear'] == 'yes') {
    $filename = 'filetoclear.txt';
    $contents = "";

    // Clear file
    file_put_contentz($filename, $contents);

    // Redirect to test.php without clearing the file a second time
    header("Location: test.php");
    exit;
}
```

If, however you didn't want to clear the file and I understood your question wrong (Blame's on me) :

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['append'])) {
    $filename = "thatonefile.txt";
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
    $contents .= $_REQUEST['append']."\n";

    header("Location: test.php");
    exit;
}

<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="append">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Using `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST` or `$_GET` will make sure that your code works whether you are calling it using get or post.

Comment: I don't want to clear, the file clear automatically after one click on link in 'test.php'.      I'm sorry if I'm not clear. Oh, sorry I didn't refresh.

Comment: Thank's for the help !